# Django query looping

Tags: arrays, django, django-queryset

I have been trying to work out a more efficient way of doing below. Does one exist? The issue is i have to do this loop 100 times (in my test case but more in real life), and there are about 100 items in each loop, which makes it really quite slow. There must be a way to compare query results something like array.filter in JS. But i cant seem to find it for Django.

```
for choice in question.answer_choices.all():
     amount = 0
     for ans in q_answers:
         if choice in ans.answers.all():
                amount += 1
```

It is basically getting the choice of answers and counting how many match to give me a result for each choice from a set of answer choices.

q_answers is just an array of answers that were given by user for 'question'.

edit:

I made slightly more efficient. But still same issues.

```
for choice in question.answer_choices.all():
    matched_answers = [ans for ans in q_answers if choice in ans.answers.all()]
    amount = len(matched_answers)
```

Structure:

````
class ReportUserAnswers(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(ReportQuestionnaireQuestion)
    text_answer = models.TextField(blank=True)
    answers = models.ManyToManyField(ReportQuestionAnswerChoices)
    images = models.ManyToManyField(ReportImage)

answers = (
     ReportUserAnswers.objects.filter()
       .select_related("question")
       .prefetch_related(
           "question__answer_choices", 
           "answers"
     )
            
)

q_answers = [answer for answer in answers if answer.question == question]
```
````

Comment: Can you provide your models, and where q_answer is defined?

Comment: Yes, i think i will need to work out annotate counts but its quite a chain. I just need to leave for an hour or so but will post structure when back as ill strip any stuff not needed. Thank you for your comment. "Managed to add before i left", its a wider thing thats needs work but im trying to tackle bit by bit.